# Javascript - "this" scope issue fix

Tags: javascript, callback, scope, this

I've been doing some playing with Javascript callbacks and understand the scope issue around "this" and how to eliminate it by using "call" or "apply" and passing in the object reference.

However, I've discovered something, and I'd like to know whether the following is bad practice? As it eliminates scope issues by purely using the object name instead "this". Say I have a function which has a callback, e.g:

```
function getUserInput(firstName, lastName, callback) {
   callback(firstName, lastName);
}
```

And an object like this:

```
var clientData = {
  id: 1,
  fullName: "Not Set",
  setUserName: function (firstName, lastName) {
  //this.fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;
  clientData.fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;
  }
}
```

To execute and see the output of the code I do the following:

```
 getUserInput("Ann", "Other", clientData.setUserName);

 console.log(clientData.fullName);
```

Which gives me "Ann Other". Perfect! Whereas if I'd uncommented the "this.fullName" line and commented out "clientData.fullName", I would have got "Not Set" and window.fullName would have contained "Ann Other" (traditional scope issue of "this" being attached to the global window).

Granted, this is a primitive example but is this bad practice? It would now now mean I never have a problem of accessing local properties in a callback function. I also don't need to use "call" or "apply" functions and pass in the object reference so that I can access "this.propertyName" under the correct scope. Any answers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it’s kind of bad practice. Given support, use [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
getUserInput("Ann", "Other", clientData.setUserName.bind(clientData));
```

(This is less redundant when you have a prototype to work off of.)

Or, the foolproof-but-not-so-pretty solution:

```
getUserInput("Ann", "Other", function(firstName, lastName) {
    clientData.setUserName(firstName, lastName);
});
```

Bonus ES6 mode (but if you have ES6, why aren’t you using `bind`?)

```
getUserInput("Ann", "Other", (...args) => clientData.setUserName(...args));
```

Answer (score 0):

Citing object's name inside its methods is definitely not a good practice since if you change your object's name you should change the method's implementation.

I would recommend you to use:

```
 getUserInput("Ann", "Other", clientData.setUserName.bind(clientData));

 console.log(clientData.fullName);
```

The issue happens because you invoke the callback `callback(firstName, lastName);` without the `.` operator, which associates the method invocation with specific context.

`bind` is part of ES5, if you are looking for wider browser compatibility you can:

```
 getUserInput("Ann", "Other", function (data) {
     clientData.setUserName.apply(clientData, arguments);
 });

 console.log(clientData.fullName);
```

Comment: the "data" param is not really need though surely? As the arguments param provides the values for the setUserName function?

Comment: Yes I like the bind method and it makes sense. I was just curious, as what I stumbled upon worked perfectly fine and understand I would have to rename things if the method name changed (an unlikely but easy change in some respect). 

I also appreciate I could use "apply" or "call" and pass in the context object. 

There's also the other way accessing the properties and avoid scope issues of setting a property of "self = this;". Then accessing properties via object.self.propertyName. I'm just curious as what is seen as good and bad practice really given that it can be a very misunderstood area.